# Transfer video from camera to OPENCV client with ++ TCP IP

Tags: c++, opencv

Good time of the day!
My task is to write a client (computer) and a server (video camera). The server will write video to the buffer until the client connects. As soon as the client connects, the recording stops immediately and a buffer with the recorded video is transferred to the server. It is then saved to an .avi file. File transfer occurs via TCP IP
I used Opencv C++.

**The main problem is that the server transmits only 1 frame to the client, an error somewhere in sending data or receiving. I need the full number of frames recorded before to be sent.**

I send only 1 frame, an error is somewhere in sending or receiving data. Guys, I already checked everything, I can't find the error, please help.

Client(PC):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int recv_size;
Mat frame;
std::vector<uchar> buffer;
int size = 0;

int main() {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.3.11");

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) { // connect to the server
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }

    if ((recv_size = recv(sock, (char*)&size, sizeof(uint32_t), 0)) != sizeof(uint32_t)) { //get buffer size
        perror("recv");
        exit(3);
    }

    cout << "SIZE FRAME: " << size << endl;


    VideoWriter outputVideo;
    Size S = Size((int)1920, (int)1080);//image size
    outputVideo.open("receive.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'), 25, S, true);//opening the receive.avi file for writing

    buffer.resize(size);//change the client's buffer to match the size of the server's buffer
    int bytes_received = 0;
while (bytes_received < size) {
    int chunk_size = min(size - bytes_received, 4096); // accept up to 4096 bytes at a time
    int recv_size = recv(sock, &buffer[bytes_received], chunk_size, 0);//receiving data from the server
    if (recv_size <= 0) {//if received is less than or equal to 0, then exit from the loop
        perror("recv");
        exit(3);
    }
    bytes_received += chunk_size;//increase the amount of received
}
    cout << "IDET DO IMDECODE " << recv_size << endl;

    frame = imdecode(buffer, IMREAD_COLOR);//convert data to Mat format
    outputVideo << frame;//write the buffer to the receive.avi file with the specified parameters
    close(sock);
    outputVideo.release();//release outputVideo

    return 0;
}
```

Server (video camera):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int c,new_socket;
std::vector<uchar> buffer;
std::vector<uchar> arrak;
int i=0,k=0;
int bbytee;
Mat image;
int bytes=0;

int main() {
    int sock,listener;
    std::vector<uchar> buf;
    std::vector<int> params(2);
    params[0] = cv::IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION;
    params[1] = 10;
    struct sockaddr_in addr,client;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if(sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // set non-blocking mode

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 

    VideoCapture cap(2); 

        if(!cap.isOpened()) { 
            cout<< "Could not open the camera" <<  endl;
            close(sock);
            return -1;
        }
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) { 
        perror("[server] binding failed!");
        exit(2);
    }

    Mat frame = Mat::zeros(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3); 
    int imgSize = frame.cols*frame.rows*3; 

    listen(sock, 1); // listen for connections

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // structure size

    while (true) {

        puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
        new_socket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);// receive socket
        cout << "New_socket: " << new_socket << endl;
        cap >> frame;//read from cap to frame
        imencode(".jpg", frame, buffer,params); //transcode to buffer buffer

               if(frame.empty()) {
                   cerr<<"[client] VideoCapture(0) error!"<<endl;
               }

               cout<< ++i << ":"<< frame.isContinuous()<<"," <<frame.size()<<endl;

        if(new_socket == -1) {//if there is no client connection, then...
            puts("Connection not accepted");
            cout << "new_socket = " << new_socket << "\n";
        } else {//if the client is connected, then ..
             int size = buffer.size()*sizeof buffer[0];//define buffer size
             send(new_socket, &size, sizeof(size), 0);

             cout << "Razmer" << size << endl;
            cout << "Transmission started" << endl;

           bytes=send(new_socket,buffer.data(), buffer.size()*sizeof buffer[0], 0);// pass the buffer size to the client
           cout << "BYTES: "<<bytes<<endl;


            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "END" << endl;
    close(sock); 
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a program, but it doesn't work correctly. Sends only 1 frame.

Comment: You added a lot of output statements to your code to follow it's progress, Suggest that you include the client and server output in the question to help everyone else follow what's going on.

Comment: Fine,ok if it helps me decide

Comment: Hello @konstitycii, Welcome to StackOverflow!
Your question needs to be more focused. Did you debug your program? At which state are you in your search for the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One obvious problem is `bytes_received += chunk_size;`. You surely need `bytes_received += recv_size;`.

Comment: The main problem is that the server transmits only 1 frame to the client, an error somewhere in sending data or receiving

Comment: Highlighted the main problem in bold